# I've created a software RAID on SUSE EL 10 and now I need to monitor it

Tags: raid, software-raid

I have created a Software Raid using the yast2 GUI on SUSE ES 10/11.  The raid works great and it's a raid 5.  I have 5 Drives they are cheap 2GB Cases that have 2 - 1TB Drives in each case (Serial ATA Drives) and I connect them in via Esata to the motherboard.  The problem I have as this is "cheap" storage when of the the 5 drives goes out on the RAID I seem to have no logs of any issues and it get's harder and harder to write to it until it dies.  I use SAMBA to mount the 4TB parition to my PC's in my home on a GIG network.
My question is this, are there any good (Free) tools in Linux to monitor a raid or the drives on the raid to detect any problems???  I haven't found any yet and was just wondering if some exist.

Answer (score 1):

mdadm  comes together with the software raid functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `mdadm` to create software RAID in Linux (it's probably what YAST is using internally) - the `man` page includes this gem:

> Running
>
> ```
> mdadm --monitor --scan -1
> ```
>
> from  a  cron  script  will  ensure regular notification of any degraded arrays.

I use the following (`-1` is the short version of `--oneshot`):

```
$ cat /etc/cron.hourly/mdadm 
#! /bin/sh

set -e

mdadm --monitor --scan --oneshot
```

Install postfix, set your email address as an alias from root in `/etc/aliases`, run `newaliases` to update the database, and expect hourly email if anything breaks.